# What's the difference between battlefield 4 and battlefield 4 deluxe edition?

Tags: battlefield-4

I expected battlefield 4 deluxe edition to be more expensive than bf4 normal edition but when I went on game stop bf4 deluxe edition is 1.50 and bf4 is 9.99 so what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty normal for older games, having the so called "Special Edition" drop price. The Deluxe Edition includes an extra DLC (China Rising) and 3 Gold BattlePacks. It's not much compared to the regular edition, so it's definitely worth it picking that up since it's cheaper.

BF4 also has a Premium pack with a lot of DLC, but that one probably goes for way more.